# Scala 3 + http4s problem with encode/decode json

Tags: scala, scala-3, http4s

I have a Scala 3 project (3.0.0 version) and I'm trying to build simple Rest API with http4s.

I have a problem with decoding/encoding JSON.

I'm building my code based on [http4s.g8](https://github.com/http4s/http4s.g8).

The issue occurs on [this line](https://github.com/http4s/http4s.g8/blob/b3634e8fb641aaf7521ddd8c37021dcd1be85e42/src/main/g8/src/main/scala/%24package__packaged%24/Jokes.scala#L23):

```
implicit val jokeDecoder: Decoder[Joke] = deriveDecoder[Joke]
```

Compile error:

> no implicit argument of type `deriving.Mirror.Of[com.example.quickstart.Jokes.Joke]` was found for parameter `A` of method `deriveDecoder` in object `semiauto`

Is there some change in Scala 3 which makes it different?

My dependencies

```
scalaVersion := "3.0.0"

val Http4sVersion = "0.23.6"
val CirceVersion = "0.14.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.http4s"      %% "http4s-blaze-server" % Http4sVersion,
  "org.http4s"      %% "http4s-blaze-client" % Http4sVersion,
  "org.http4s"      %% "http4s-circe"        % Http4sVersion,
  "org.http4s"      %% "http4s-dsl"          % Http4sVersion,

  "io.circe"        %% "circe-core"          % CirceVersion,
  "io.circe"        %% "circe-generic"       % CirceVersion
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
final case class Joke(joke: String) extends AnyVal
```

is the cuprit. Rewrite it as

```
final case class Joke(joke: String)
```

it should work